# Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

При подключении к Postgresql ошибка

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-07-15 23:38:07.703 ERROR 12732 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

проперти

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sales
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root
```

помник

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- DataBase support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: `spring.datasource.url` указано в `application.properties`?

Comment: да. я решил. версия jpa driver откатил к 2.0.0 и все прошло